# Не выбранный <select>

Tags: php, html

Возник вопрос как есть 4 селекта как. Если какой то из них не выбран то есть по умолчанию стоит первый  не учитывать его и выводить данные из бд на основе других выбранных. То есть не учитывать не выбранные  при выводе данных из бд подскажите кто знает

```
<html> 
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="smb" value="Применить">
<select name="numbers">
<option>Выберите номер</option>
<option value="№1">№1</option>
<option value="№2">№2</option>
<option value="№3">№3</option>
<option value="№4">№4</option>
<option value="№5">№5</option>
<option value="№6">№6</option>
<option value="№7">№7</option>
<option value="№8">№8</option>
<option value="№9">№9</option>
<option value="№10">№10</option>
<option value="№11">№11</option>
<option value="№12">№12</option>
</select>
<?php
// устанавливаем первый и последний год диапазона
$yearArray = range(2000, 2030);
?>
<!-- выводим выпадающий список -->
<select name="yearrs">
    <option>Выберите год</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($yearArray as $year) {
        // если вы хотите выбрать конкретный год
        $selected = ($year == 1999) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="langgs">
<option>Выберите язык</option>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "dtctyybqltym")|| die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("scat")|| die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = 'SELECT * FROM lang';
$result = mysql_query ( $query ) or die ( 'Query failed: ' . mysql_error ( ) );
   while ( $line = mysql_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
      echo '<option value="' . $line [ 'lang' ] . '">' . $line [ 'lang' ] . "</option>";
   }
?>          
</select>
<select name="siglaas">
<option>Выберите местонахождение</option>
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM sigla';
$result = mysql_query ( $query ) or die ( 'Query failed: ' . mysql_error ( ) );
   while ( $line = mysql_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
      echo '<option value="' . $line [ 'name' ] . '">' . $line [ 'name' ] . "</option>";
   }
?>          
</select>
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['smb']))
{
$number = $_POST['numbers'];
$yearr = $_POST['yearrs'];
$langg = trim($_POST['langgs']);
$siglaa = trim($_POST['siglaas']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `year`, `namev`, `lang`, `vid`, `period`, `sigla` FROM `osnov` WHERE `name` LIKE '1%' AND `namev`='$number' AND `year`='$yearr' AND `lang`='$langg' AND `sigla`='$siglaa'");
} else 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `year`, `namev`, `lang`, `vid`, `period`, `sigla` FROM `osnov` WHERE `name` LIKE '1%'");   

echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><th>Наименование</th><th>Год выпуска</th><th>Номер выпуска</th><th>Язык</th><th>Вид</th><th>Периодичность</th><th>Местонахождение</th></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
extract($row); 
echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$year</td><td>$namev</td><td>$lang</td><td>$vid</td><td>$period</td><td>$sigla</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще бы вынести работу с базой(модель) отдельно, и работать с моделью через нэймспэйсы или инклюды.

Как вариант предварительно создать массив

```
$data = array(
   'numbers' => '',
   'yearrs' => '',
   'langgs' => '',
   'siglaa' => ''
);
```

Селектам задать name в формате data[name]

```
<select name="data[numbers]"></select>
```

После получить данные через `$request = $_POST['data']` и пробежаться через `foreach` собирая строку фильтра

```
foreach($request as $key => $value)
{
    if( array_key_exists($key,$data) )
    {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$filter = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if( $value != '' )
    {
        $filter .= " AND `".$key."`='".$value."'";
    }
}
```

В результате получим такой запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `year`, `namev`, `lang`, `vid`, `period`, `sigla` FROM `osnov` WHERE `name` LIKE '1%'".$filter);
```

Comment: Или можно немного наоборот, создать пустой массив, а в 1 фориче сменить проверку на `!array_key_exists`

Comment: Попробовал по вашему примеру выбрал в селекте №2 c помощью var_dump($_POST); вывел данные чтобы посмотреть правильно ли все формируется вывелось `array(5) { ["numbers"]=> string(4) "№2" ["yearrs"]=> string(4) "none" ["langgs"]=> string(4) "none" ["siglaas"]=> string(4) "none" ["smb"]=> string(18) "Применить" }` впринципе все верно как я понимаю но в таблицу данные по этому условию так и не вывелись не пойму в чем может быть причина

Comment: @JonJones напиши мне в  [ВК](http://vk.com/el_paramore)

Answer (score 1):

Установите пустые `<option value="none" selected> </option>` в селектах, сделайте их дефолтными.
Далее ловите в PHP что-то по типу:

```
if($_POST['numbers'] == 'none'){
$number = '';
} else {
$number = $_POST['numbers'];
}
```

Хотя какой-то индийский кодинг для большого кол-ва полей получается.

Comment: Попробывал сделать так для четырех селектов 
 но ни чего не выводит вроде по примеру сделал я как понял он все ровно используеться пустое занчение $number = '';  и выводит по нему `if(isset($_POST['smb']))
{
if($_POST['numbers'] == 'none'){
$number = '';
} else {
$number = $_POST['numbers'];
} 
if($_POST['yearrs'] == 'none'){
$yearr = '';
} else {
$yearr = $_POST['yearrs'];
}
if($_POST['langgs'] == 'none'){
$langg = '';
} else {
$langg = trim($_POST['langgs']);
}
if($_POST['siglaas'] == 'none'){
$siglaa = '';
} else {
$siglaa = trim($_POST['siglaas']);
}`